# Files directory in android

Tags: android, installation

I have a file into "files" directory in my android project in eclipse, but when run the application in my device or in a device emulator, i don't find this directory

i want to put this file in /data/data/MYPACKAGE/files/mifile.txt during the installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put it under assets folder and use getAssets() to access it

```
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("files/myfile.txt");
```

this will return the InputStream from the file then you can read it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getRessourceAsStream(String path)` or simply use the assets folder and `getAssets()`